# Matlab - short format of number variable in the plot title

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, number-formatting

I am trying to place a variable into a plot title but I cannot produce formatting of 4 decimal places. How to avoid the float format in the title?

This is the code I use

```
subplot(3,2,1);
hist(X,10);
str=sprintf('X N=%d,Y=%d',N,Y)
M=sum(X)/N
Mean=sprintf('Mean=%0.4d',M)
title({str,Mean})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%f` as the [format specifier for float values](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0z60p-1). Changing your code

```
Mean=sprintf('Mean=%0.4d',M)
```

to

```
Mean=sprintf('Mean=%0.4f',M)
```

will print `M` with 4 decimal places of accuracy. If you want to print `M` without any decimal places then you need to use `%.0f`

```
Mean=sprintf('Mean=%.0f',M)
```

`%.0f` will print a `double` or `float` value with 0 decimal places and appear as if you printed an integer with `%d`.

---

If your variable `X` has `N` elements than using the builtin MATLAB function [`mean()`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html) will produce the same output as `sum(X) / N`.

---

**Note**: You should be careful of your variable names. MATLAB includes a `mean()` function which you don't want to overwrite by calling a variable `mean`. MATLAB variable names are case-sensitive so `Mean` is ok but `mean` isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `num2str` function. For example:

```
mean(y)
a=num2str(ans,5)
plot(x,y)
title(['sometext ' a])
```

`5` in `num2str` parameters shows maximum number of significant digits. And `a` is now a `string`.
By the way you can use `mean` build-in function instead your formula.