# matlab rename plot title automatically with loop

Tags: matlab, plot, title

I have trouble renaming my plots in a loop. I tried

```
for Yearnumber 2000:2018
 etc etc
title('Plot for year %g',Yearnumber,'FontSize',20);

end
```

similar to what I type into sprintf but it doesnt work. Is there any way to make it loop through the years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matlab - short format of number variable in the plot title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114938/matlab-short-format-of-number-variable-in-the-plot-title). The dupe shows how to use `sprintf`, just use a different identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `sprintf` within the `title()`

```
for Yearnumber = 2000:2018
    title( sprintf( 'Plot for year %g', Yearnumber ), 'FontSize', 20);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`spirntf` is a good answer, and you can also do this:

```
for Yearnumber = 2000:2018
    title( ['Plot for year' num2str(Yearnumber)], 'FontSize', 20);
end
```